# how to collect three arguments in mapper output .Is there any way

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to map Reduce and hadoop concept.So please help

I have near about 100 files containing data in this format

```
conf/iceis/GochenouerT01a:::John E. Gochenouer::Michael L. Tyler:::Voyeurism, Exhibitionism, and Privacy on the Internet.
```

which i am supposed to do via map reduce algorithm. Now in the output I want to display

```
John E. Gochenoue Voyeurism .
John E. Gochenoue Exhibitionism 
John E. Gochenoue and 
John E. Gochenoue privacy
John E. Gochenoue on
John E. Gochenoue the
John E. Gochenoue internet   
Michael L. Tyler   Voyeurism .
Michael L. Tyler   Exhibitionism 
Michael L. Tyler   and 
Michael L. Tyler   privacy
Michael L. Tyler   on
Michael L. Tyler   the
Michael L. Tyler   internet
```

so now it is single line. So there are 'n' number of lines like that containing plenty of names and plenty of books.

So if I consider one document with 110 lines. Can I have an output of my mapper like this

```
John E. Gochenoue Voyeurism    1  
John E. Gochenoue Exhibitionism 3 
Michael L. Tyler   on           7
```

I.E.
To say it displays the name and the work followed by the occourence of the word in the document and finally after reduce it should display the name followed by the words the name has against it and the combined frequency of the word it has occoured in 'n' document.

Well i know output.collecter() but it takes two arguments

```
output.collect(arg0, arg1)
```

Is there any method so as to collect three values like name,word and occourence of word

The following is my code

```
public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
            OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {
        String line = value.toString();
        /*
         * StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line); while
         * (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) { word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
         * output.collect(word, one);
         */

        String strToSplit[] = line.split(":::");
        String end = strToSplit[strToSplit.length - 1];
        String[] names = strToSplit[1].split("::");
        for (String name : names) {
            StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(end, " ");
            while (tokens.hasMoreElements()) {
                output.collect(arg0, arg1)
                System.out.println(tokens.nextElement());
            }
        }

    }
}

public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements
        Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values,
            OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {
        int sum = 0;
        while (values.hasNext()) {
            sum += values.next().get();
        }
        output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(example.class);
    conf.setJobName("wordcount");

    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, "/home/vishal/workspace/hw3data");
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf,
            new Path("/home/vishal/nmnmnmnmnm"));

    JobClient.runJob(conf);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the mapper class when passing along the tokenized strings, you need to essentially group for the same key when you want to count.

This means that counting the number of times a person has used a word would require you to generate a key that looked like this `John Smith<delimiter>Word`.  The delimiter can be anything you want. Most people use tabs so as to keep it a TSV in the final reducer output.

So to correct your output.collect statement would be to change it to something like this:

```
output.collect(new Text(name + "\t" + tokens.nextElement()), new IntWritable(1));
```

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to write a Text (one of the hadoop Writable implementations) whose string content is a number of tab-separated values.  That's how you can easily pass complex values between mappers and reducers.

Of course, the more industrial strength approach is to write your own Writable.  Writables are basically pojo's with special serialize/deserialize behavior.  In this case your writable would have three properties.